# XCode Server: Opening import file for module 'MobileCoreServices': Permission denied

Tags: swift, xcode

When running a bot in XCode 8 and using Swift 3 code, I'm getting this error:
Opening import file for module 'MobileCoreServices': Permission denied

I'm using Carthage. I run the macOS Server in another user account on the same machine.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: `carthage update` on building machine solves this issue, but it's not an option for distributed builds

Answer (score 0):

I got this same error. What fixed it for me was to delete my `Carthage/` folder in the project directory and to rebuild using `carthage update`, not `sudo carthage update`.