# Carthage: Opening import file for module * Permission denied

Tags: swift, xcode, carthage

I see this issue for Carthage has been asked a few times but I haven't been able to find a working solution. I've tried all of the suggestions in these threads that have similar issues but none of them works.

[XCode Server: Opening import file for module 'MobileCoreServices': Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40036913/xcode-server-opening-import-file-for-module-mobilecoreservices-permission-de)

[Opening import file for module 'Swift': Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26258264/opening-import-file-for-module-swift-permission-denied)

[Opening import file for module 'Swift' Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30196440/opening-import-file-for-module-swift-permission-denied/30936301#30936301)

Is there a particular reason why I get a "Permission denied" error from xcode?

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly new with Carthage so perhaps someone with more experience can elaborate further. In my case, all I had to do was clone the project again, and run:

```
carthage bootstrap --platform iOS
```

**Without sudo**

By using --platform iOS I was making sure nothing was being installed for macOS or tvOS which was causing issues. Also, using sudo was getting all the dependencie but for some reason I was getting the error I posted on this question.